# Reduce Execution Time in MYSQL from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database

i have a table which is relevant GPS application in mysql. whenever i am executing from asp.net application it showing fetal error. so i have decided to run in mysql, it will take more than 1 min(exactly 70 sec) for executing the SP. is it possible to sort out the issues.

Further information:

table 1 : server_gpsdata(it contains gps data. it locks every 10 secs from gps device).

```
select * from server_gpsdata SD 
INNER JOIN mstcab MC on MC.cabid= SD.cabid 
INNER JOIN server_tblstatus TS on TS.statusid= MC.CabStatusid 
INNER JOIN carmaster CM on CM.carid= MC.carid 
INNER JOIN cabtype CT on CT.cabtypeid= CM.sizeid 
where date(SD.cur_datetime) =current_date and 
      MC.Cabid not in (select D.cabid from trncabdriver D 
                       where date(D.logintime)=current_date) and 
      SD.gpsdataid in (select max(SGD.gpsdataid) from server_gpsdata SGD 
                       where date(SGD.cur_datetime)=current_date 
                       group by SGD.cabid);
```

Comment: We'd need to see the query and the tables involved, probably.

Comment: Could you provide more informations like the relevant code and your installation details?

Comment: It would be good try to extend query timeout but you'll have to provide more details about your data access components.

Comment: Also the query plan for the query, the structures of the tables involved and any indexes on them.

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding some more specifics.

Comment: table 1 : server_gpsdata(it contains gps data. it locks every 10 secs from gps device). select * from server_gpsdata SD INNER JOIN 
mstcab MC on MC.cabid= SD.cabid INNER JOIN server_tblstatus TS on TS.statusid= MC.CabStatusid INNER JOIN  carmaster CM on CM.carid= MC.carid INNER JOIN cabtype CT on CT.cabtypeid= CM.sizeid  where date(SD.cur_datetime)  =current_date and MC.Cabid not in (select D.cabid from trncabdriver D where date(D.logintime)=current_date) and  SD.gpsdataid in   (select max(SGD.gpsdataid) from server_gpsdata SGD where date(SGD.cur_datetime)=current_date  group by SGD.cabid);

Answer (score 1):

The following should show a significant improvement in performance:

```
select SD.*, MC.*, TS.*, CM.*, CT.* from 
(select max(SGD.gpsdataid) maxgpsdataid from server_gpsdata SGD 
 where date(SGD.cur_datetime)=current_date 
 group by SGD.cabid) SDM
INNER JOIN server_gpsdata SD ON SDM.maxgpsdataid = SD.gpsdataid
INNER JOIN mstcab MC on MC.cabid= SD.cabid 
INNER JOIN server_tblstatus TS on TS.statusid= MC.CabStatusid 
INNER JOIN carmaster CM on CM.carid= MC.carid 
INNER JOIN cabtype CT on CT.cabtypeid= CM.sizeid 
LEFT JOIN trncabdriver D ON MC.Cabid= D.Cabid AND date(D.logintime)=current_date
where D.Cabid IS NULL
```

Note that both the existing and proposed queries are returning all columns from the server_gpsdata, mstcab, server_tblstatus, carmaster and cabtype tables - the query is likely to perform better if only the columns that are actually required are selected in the query.

Comment: Agree with the above, but probably needs the check for SD.cur_datetime adding

Comment: @Kickstart: Definitely not - the SDM/SGD.cur_datetime check achieves the same effect, while removing the condition from SD should ensure that SD records are accessed via gpsdataid (which should have an index on it).

Comment: @ Mark Bannister  - mmm. Possibly. It would depend on gpsdataid, and whether it is a unique key for that table. It may not be. For example there could be duplicates with different dates, which would mess up the join from the subselect back onto server_gpsdata. However this would depend entirely on the table design which unfortunately hasn't been specified. If this were the case it could also be fixed by returning the date from the subselect and using that in the join.